# Issues using a Fedex Webservice via WSDL/SOAP

Tags: php, api, soap, wsdl, fedex

I downloaded the sample code to request a rate from fedex's website... i placed the WSDL file in the proper location, I have my acct number, password, meter number, and key. When I run the script I get this error:

> Error in processing transaction.
>   ERROR
>   prof
>   1000
>   Authentication Failed

The script they give is as follows, and yes i do actually replace the XXX and YYY everywhere it says.:

```
<?php

// Copyright 2009, FedEx Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Version 7.0.0

require_once('fedex-common.php5');

$newline = "<br />";
//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "RateService_v7.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array('UserCredential' =>
                                      array('Key' => 'XXX', 'Password' => 'YYY')); // Replace 'XXX' and 'YYY' with FedEx provided credentials 
$request['ClientDetail'] = array('AccountNumber' => 'XXX', 'MeterNumber' => 'YYY');// Replace 'XXX' with your account and meter number
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request v7 using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array('ServiceId' => 'crs', 'Major' => '7', 'Intermediate' => '0', 'Minor' => '0');
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'FEDEX_GROUND'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = array('Address' => array(
                                          'StreetLines' => array('10 Fed Ex Pkwy'), // Origin details
                                          'City' => 'Memphis',
                                          'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TN',
                                          'PostalCode' => '38115',
                                          'CountryCode' => 'US'));
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = array('Address' => array (
                                               'StreetLines' => array('13450 Farmcrest Ct'), // Destination details
                                               'City' => 'Herndon',
                                               'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'VA',
                                               'PostalCode' => '20171',
                                               'CountryCode' => 'US'));
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = array('PaymentType' => 'SENDER',
                                                        'Payor' => array('AccountNumber' => 'XXX', // Replace 'XXX' with payor's account number
                                                                     'CountryCode' => 'US'));
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'ACCOUNT'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'LIST'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '2';
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageDetailSpecified'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageDetail'] = 'INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES';  //  Or PACKAGE_SUMMARY
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = array('0' => array('Weight' => array('Value' => 2.0,
                                                                                    'Units' => 'LB'),
                                                                                    'Dimensions' => array('Length' => 10,
                                                                                        'Width' => 10,
                                                                                        'Height' => 3,
                                                                                        'Units' => 'IN')),
                                                                   '1' => array('Weight' => array('Value' => 5.0,
                                                                                    'Units' => 'LB'),
                                                                                    'Dimensions' => array('Length' => 20,
                                                                                        'Width' => 20,
                                                                                        'Height' => 10,
                                                                                        'Units' => 'IN')));
try 
{
    $response = $client ->getRates($request);

    if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR')
    {
        printRequestResponse($client);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Error in processing transaction.'. $newline. $newline; 
        foreach ($response -> Notifications as $notification)
        {           
            if(is_array($response -> Notifications))
            {              
               echo $notification -> Severity;
               echo ': ';           
               echo $notification -> Message . $newline;
            }
            else
            {
                echo $notification . $newline;
            }
        } 
    } 

    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   

} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   printFault($exception, $client);        
}

?>
```

I am not quite sure why it isn't working, i've read about using a proxy, but I am not quite sure how i would use it in this case? Isn't the point of using SOAP and WSDL to avoid using CURL, Direct Connect type stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SoapUI ( http://www.soapui.org/ ) to contact the WSDL, what is the response you get?

(SoapUI enables you to test SOAP/Wsdl's without programming, so you can check if the calls are correct, if they are, then the problem is in your code.)

Comment: Apparently there is some propagation period with FedEx passwords and test accounts. I obtained a production key (had to registered for my own fedex account as well), and then after some searching I found I had to change the gateway to: https://gateway.fedex.com/web-services 

A little confusing, as none of that is documented. In any case it works now. Now I just need to parse this nasty XML response!

Answer (score 7):

Agree with Aditya Kumar,
or check in your wsdl file at bottom. there is a code

```
<s1:address location="https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship"/>
```

change it to

```
<s1:address location="https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

I Was also having the Same issue, i was entering the password which i was using to login, but we need to enter the password which will be sent your email address after registering for the test account information with FEDEX:

Please make sure the values you have entered below are correct:

```
if($var == 'shipaccount') Return 'Your Account Number';
if($var == 'meter')       Return 'Your meter number';
if($var == 'key')         Return 'Your key'; //These values wiil be shown in the page after registering for the test account

if($var == 'password')    Return 'Your Password'; // This will be sent to you by Fedex to your mail this is not your account password using to login
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit fedex-common.php5 file replace 'XXX' with your info in the following params

```
if($var == 'shipaccount') Return 'YOUR TEST ACCOUNT NUMBER HERE'; 
if($var == 'billaccount') Return 'YOUR TEST ACCOUNT NUMBER HERE';
if($var == 'meter') Return 'YOUR TEST METER NUMBER HERE';
if($var == 'key') Return 'YOUR TEST KEY HERE';
if($var == 'password') Return 'YOUR TEST PASSWORD HERE';
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**in library file fedex-common.php5** change following fields to provided credentials:

```
if($var == 'shipaccount') Return '123456';
if($var == 'billaccount') Return '123456';
if($var == 'dutyaccount') Return '123456';
if($var == 'accounttovalidate') Return '123456';
if($var == 'meter') Return '654321';
if($var == 'key') Return 'ASDE324dfe';
if($var == 'password') Return 'K2wedrf4ASDE324dfe';
```

**in wsdlfile ShipService_v*.wsdl** change following thing:

```
<s1:address location="https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship"/>
```

Hope it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue from earlier and found solution finally after a discussion with FedEx Technical Person.See why we are facing such error all because of  Developer Test Account we generated from developer website.One thing we should keep in mind that Test Account Number start with "6" is of Production & Key Start with "5" is Correct Test Key.So Please check your Test Key when you get Authentication problem with Error Code 1000.

Another Reason apart from this is might be your Fedex Webservice endpoint is different like for ex "https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services/track", this is Sandbox mode url and in production environment url should be like this "https://ws.fedex.com/web-services/track". There is no "beta" mode in URL for Production,So please check endpoint.