# Issue when integrating Fedex using php?

Tags: php, wsdl, fedex

I am trying to integrate FedEx. I got code from the following link [FedEx PHP Code](https://www.fedex.com/wpor/web/jsp/drclinks.jsp?links=wss/getstarted.html)

Also i found one post [FedEx WebService WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013657/issues-using-a-fedex-webservice-via-wdsl-soap)

I included the wsdl file using the code `$path_to_wsdl = "RateService_v10.wsdl";` I have given  the same code with my credentials. When i ran the php file ,i am getting the following error,

```
Error in processing transaction.

ERROR
crs
300
Package 1 - Group package count must be at least a value of 1.
Package 1 - Group package count must be at least a value of 1.
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /var/www/standard_php/php/RateWebServiceClient/test.php on line 80
```

How to fix this issue ? I want to get the shipping rate ?
Kindly advice on this

Answer (score 0):

I gave the wrong account number in fedex-common.php5

```
if($var == 'shipaccount') Return 'XXX'; //i replaced xxx with valid account number.
```