# FedEx Web Service freight rates not in response

Tags: php, fedex

I need to get FedEx Freight Rates from the FedEx Webservice API using `PHP` with `SoapClient`.  I'm using the RateService_v10.wsdl to request rates:

```
$client = new SoapClient($pathToWsdl, array('trace' => 1));

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(...);

//Setup other values... omitting $request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] so all ServiceTypes are returned into the response

$response = $client->getRates($request);

//Validate $response

foreach($response->RateReplyDetails as $details) {
    echo $details->ServiceType;
}
```

No freight service types are included in the response.  I am looking for rates for these types:

```
FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY
FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY
```

Why aren't freight rates included in the response?  How can I query FedEx to get freight rates?  Some products i need rates for are over 2,200 lbs

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No- the requirement is FedEx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a FedEx Webservice and you should probably contact them.


Comment: @bluefeet I've seen a few of these type's of questions. Since it deals with an API and has code, I think it's 62.5718% valid for SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues using a Fedex Webservice via WSDL/SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013657/issues-using-a-fedex-webservice-via-wsdl-soap)

Comment: International Priority Freight Skids weighing in excess of 2,200 lbs. require prior approval by FedEx. consequently web services are not going to process automatically.

Comment: @s_h do you have any specific documentation on this information? i'd like to read more about it

Comment: fedex developerguide2012.pdf in page 281 as an example. FedEx International Priority Freight topic. same with all other options for freight services.

Answer (score 1):

If others come across this these many years later as I did, know that FedEx freight rate requests do not work the same as parcel rates at all, and a separate request must be made for each freight method.